# Using the timeout in GetOverlappedResultEx to simulate a wait with timeout?

Tags: winapi, overlapped-io, getoverlappedresult

When using [**GetOverlapedResult**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresult) to get the result of an overlapped (i.e. asynchronous) I/O operation, you can ask **GetOverlappdResult** to *"wait"*:

```
DWORD le = ERROR_SUCCESS; //lastError = 0

if (!ReadFile(FSourceDiskHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, out bytesRead, overlapped)
{
   //The read operation did not complete synchronously. See if it's still pending.
   le = GetLastError;
   if (le == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
   {
      le = ERROR_SUCCESS;
      if (!GetOverlappedResult(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, true) // <---bWait = true 
         le = GetLastError;
   }

   if (le != ERROR_SUCCESS)
      LogFmt("Error reading source: %s (%d)', SysErrorMessage(le), le], TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR);
}
```

The part to note here is the final parameter to `GetOverlappedResult`: `bWait`:

> `bWait`
>
> If this parameter is **TRUE**, and the **Internal** member of the *lpOverlapped* structure is **STATUS_PENDING**, the function does not return until the operation has been completed. If this parameter is **FALSE** and the operation is still pending, the function returns **FALSE** and the [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) function returns **ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE**.

For my code this means:

- if the I/O completes quickly, [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) returns **true**.
- if the I/O is still *pending* then i **wait** for it to complete
- and if there's some other error, i get that error.

And this all works great.

## Mostly this all works great

I'm having an issue where the actual `ReadFile` operation is taking ***ten minutes*** to return. When it does return, it returns:

```
The device is not ready (21)
```

It's a well-known problem with this [one vendor's storage system.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7c3fc4f-4712-4442-baa6-4fd004e28c13/storage-spaces-repairvirtualdisk-storagejob-stuck-on-0?forum=winserver8gen).

What i would like to do is use the *asynchronous* capabilities of Windows to wait - but with a timeout.

And i noticed [GetOverlappedResultEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresultex), it has a sort of *timeout* parameter:

```
BOOL GetOverlappedResultEx(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesTransferred,
  DWORD        dwMilliseconds, <----------
  BOOL         bAlertable
);
```

But when i look at the documentation, this is where i get into details of Windows programming i don't understand - queued APCs, alterable waits. But it still *sounds* like what i want::

> `dwMilliseconds`
>
> The time-out interval, in milliseconds.
>
> If *dwMilliseconds* is zero and the operation is still in progress, the
>   function returns immediately and the GetLastError function returns
>   **ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE**.
>
> If *dwMilliseconds* is nonzero and the operation is still in progress,
>   the function waits until the object is signaled, an I/O completion
>   routine or APC is queued, or the interval elapses before returning.
>   Use GetLastError to get extended error information.
>
> If *dwMilliseconds* is **INFINITE**, the function returns only when the
>   object is signaled or an I/O completion routine or APC is queued.

So i try changing my function:

```
DWORD le = ERROR_SUCCESS; //lastError = 0

if (!ReadFile(FSourceDiskHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, out bytesRead, overlapped)
{
   //The read operation did not complete synchronously. See if it's still pending.
   le = GetLastError;
   if (le == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
   {
      le = ERROR_SUCCESS;
      //if (!GetOverlappedResult(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, true) // <---bWait = true 
      if (!GetOverlappedResultEx(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, 5000, False) //wait 5000 ms
         le = GetLastError;
   }

   if (le != ERROR_SUCCESS)
      LogFmt("Error reading source: %s (%d)', SysErrorMessage(le), le], TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR);
}
```

Except the call to **GetOverlappedResultEx** doesn't return in 5 seconds (5,000 ms). Instead it continues to take 10-20 minutes for the storage subsystem to get around to returning a failure.

### So i randomly try things

I see another parameter of **GetOverlappedResultsEx**:

```
`bAlertable`

If this parameter is **TRUE** and the calling thread is in the waiting state, the function returns when the system queues an I/O completion routine or APC. The calling thread then runs the routine or function. Otherwise, the function does not return, and the completion routine or APC function is not executed.

A completion routine is queued when the [ReadFileEx][5] or [WriteFileEx][5] function in which it was specified has completed. The function returns and the completion routine is called only if *bAlertable* is **TRUE**, and the calling thread is the thread that initiated the read or write operation. An APC is queued when you call [QueueUserAPC][5].
```

This doesn't *sound* like my situation:

- i'm not using `ReadFileEx`
- i'm not calling `QueueUserAPC`

But that doesn't have to stop me from randomly trying things and hope they work:

```
DWORD le = ERROR_SUCCESS; //lastError = 0

if (!ReadFile(FSourceDiskHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, out bytesRead, overlapped)
{
   //The read operation did not complete synchronously. See if it's still pending.
   le = GetLastError;
   if (le == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
   {
      le = ERROR_SUCCESS;
      //if (!GetOverlappedResult(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, true) // <---bWait = true 
      if (!GetOverlappedResultEx(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, 5000, False) //wait 5000 ms
      if (!GetOverlappedResultEx(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, 5000, True) //wait 5000 ms, alertable

         le = GetLastError;
   }

   if (le != ERROR_SUCCESS)
      LogFmt("Error reading source: %s (%d)', SysErrorMessage(le), le], TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

## So i ask Stackoverflow

Can i simulate a synchronous `ReadFile` operation but **with** a timeout, using `GetOverlappedResultEx`?

I'm sure i could eventually get a buggy hack involving messaging timers (or is that thread timers? Or is that alertable timers? and events? and my own events? Or the event in the overlap?). But i'd rather use the **good** solution rather than **my** solution.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, 5000)` ?

Comment: If you are willing to limit yourself to C++20, you can use a coroutine to do just that. [Asynchronous timeouts made easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#asynchronous-timeouts-made-easy) explains, how to use the pre-built `wait_for` function. The implementation does essentially, what Jonathan Potter suggested.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - but `GetOverlappedResultEx` and do internal `WaitForSingleObjectEx(overlapped.hEvent, dwMilliseconds, bAlertable)`

Comment: *Except the call to `GetOverlappedResultEx` doesn't return in 5 seconds (5,000 ms). Instead it continues to take 10-20 minutes for the storage subsystem to get around to returning a failure.* - this can not be. you make some error here

Comment: `GetOverlappedResultEx(FSourceDiskHandle, overlapped, out bytesRead, 5000, False)` will return not late than after 5 second, if you say *Instead it continues to take 10-20 minutes* - this is 100% error in your call `GetOverlappedResultEx` - this api will wait only on event from overlapped and independent from file. so can not be more than your wait timeout

Comment: @RbMm You are somewhat correct. I added more logging and i realized that GetOverlappedResultEx isn't one one taking 10 minutes to return. It's the asynchronous call to `ReadFile` with overlap. After 10 minutes the call to `ReadFile` returns **FALSE**, with `GetLastError` of 0.

Comment: yes, this can be. really this already depended from driver, which implement device, on which you create file. correct implemented driver - must return immediately. but possible and another implementation. when driver not return control.. in this case - we can not do something. bad driver

Comment: correct written driver, if can not complete operation  immediately - must save IRP, add cancel routine to it (via `IoSetCancelRoutine`), for we can cancel I/O, and return `STATUS_PENDING`. but if driver not do this - here we can not do any. if driver begin wait on our thread - we can not break this wait. no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i simulate a synchronous `ReadFile` operation but with a timeout,
>   using `GetOverlappedResultEx`?

yes, you can, exactly like you and try already. and this is not simulation. this will be exactly synchronous file read. because synchronous read - this is asynchronous read + wait in place when I/O complete. so code can be next:

```
ULONG ReadFileTimeout(HANDLE hFile, 
               PVOID lpBuffer, 
               ULONG nNumberOfBytesToRead, 
               PULONG lpNumberOfBytesRead, 
               PLARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset, 
               ULONG dwMilliseconds)
{
    OVERLAPPED ov;
    ov.Offset = ByteOffset->LowPart;
    ov.OffsetHigh = ByteOffset->HighPart;

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    if (ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        dwError = ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, &ov) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

        if (dwError == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            dwError = GetOverlappedResultEx(0/*yes, not need hFile*/, 
                &ov, lpNumberOfBytesRead, dwMilliseconds, FALSE) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
        }

        CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

note that you must (in case asynchronous file) always explicit use Byte offset, from where read data.

the `GetOverlappedResultEx` in general do next - check the `OVERLAPPED` - are I/O complete (simply compare `Internal` with `STATUS_PENDING`), and if not ( still `Internal == STATUS_PENDING`) and you want wait - it call `WaitForSingleObjectEx` with `hEvent` from `OVERLAPPED` and transferred `dwMilliseconds`, and `bAlertable`. if `hEvent` signaled (`WAIT_OBJECT_0` returned from `WaitForSingleObjectEx`) `GetOverlappedResultEx` decide that I/O complete and return result from `OVERLAPPED`, otherwise appropriate error returned.

but in case the `ReadFile` itself not return control and wait - here impossible do something. this mean that driver begin wait on your thread. and no any way break this driver wait. look like this exactly your case. when you use asynchronous file - driver must not wait, but .. sometimes (bad written driver) this can be